# Smooth scrolling jquery plugin resets scroll start point on refresh. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I came across [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/animation/jQuery-Plugin-For-Smooth-Mouse-Scrolling-scrollSpeed.html) very easy to use and implement jquery plugin for enabling smooth scrolling on a website to help with the look of parallax effects.

Now to implement it I made a .js script which is just

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // $fn.scrollSpeed(step, speed, easing);
    jQuery.scrollSpeed(100, 800);
    
});
```

as per the instructions. The whole plugin obviously has it's own .js file which I guess I'll include the contents of,

```
// Custom scrolling speed with jQuery
// Source: github.com/ByNathan/jQuery.scrollSpeed
// Version: 1.0.2

(function($) {
    
    jQuery.scrollSpeed = function(step, speed, easing) {
        
        var $document = $(document),
            $window = $(window),
            $body = $('html, body'),
            option = easing || 'default',
            root = 0,
            scroll = false,
            scrollY,
            scrollX,
            view;
            
        if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled)
        
            return false;
            
        $window.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
            
            var deltaY = e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY,
                detail = e.originalEvent.detail;
                scrollY = $document.height() > $window.height();
                scrollX = $document.width() > $window.width();
                scroll = true;
            
            if (scrollY) {
                
                view = $window.height();
                    
                if (deltaY < 0 || detail > 0)
            
                    root = (root + view) >= $document.height() ? root : root += step;
                
                if (deltaY > 0 || detail < 0)
            
                    root = root <= 0 ? 0 : root -= step;
                
                $body.stop().animate({
            
                    scrollTop: root
                
                }, speed, option, function() {
            
                    scroll = false;
                
                });
            }
            
            if (scrollX) {
                
                view = $window.width();
                    
                if (deltaY < 0 || detail > 0)
            
                    root = (root + view) >= $document.width() ? root : root += step;
                
                if (deltaY > 0 || detail < 0)
            
                    root = root <= 0 ? 0 : root -= step;
                
                $body.stop().animate({
            
                    scrollLeft: root
                
                }, speed, option, function() {
            
                    scroll = false;
                
                });
            }
            
            return false;
            
        }).on('scroll', function() {
            
            if (scrollY && !scroll) root = $window.scrollTop();
            if (scrollX && !scroll) root = $window.scrollLeft();
            
        }).on('resize', function() {
            
            if (scrollY && !scroll) view = $window.height();
            if (scrollX && !scroll) view = $window.width();
            
        });       
    };
    
    jQuery.easing.default = function (x,t,b,c,d) {
    
        return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
    };
    
})(jQuery);
```

Now my issue is that everytime I refresh my page: http://danceforovariancancer.com.au

and either click one of my navbar links or if I've refreshed when I was half way down the page, it resets the scroll start position and rushes the page up to the top before you can scroll anywhere. Can I replace a number in either of these .js files with something like current scrollTop or?

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The plug-in apparently keeps track of the current scroll top offset in the *root* variable, which it initialises to 0 when you call `jQuery.scrollSpeed` on page load.

So I propose to change the following line, near the top of that function:

```
        var ...
            root = 0,
```

by:

```
        var ...
            root = $window.scrollTop(),
```

After further analysis, this plug-in has some other things to improve:

- It captures the resize event to set the *view* variable, but that is useless since the rest of the code also sets that variable before using it.
- It defines several variables in the *scrollSpeed* scope which are better scoped to the *mousewheel* event handler, as they have no use elsewhere
- It keeps track of the scroll offset in the *root* variable, also in the *scroll* event handler, but it is better to just request it on the spot whenever it is needed. This makes the *scroll* event handler unnecessary.
- It keeps track of whether a scrolling animation is ongoing in the *scroll* variable, but it's value is never read, nor exposed. So I suggest to remove it. Animation can be detected by `$('html,body').is(':animated');`
- It has very similar code for horizontal and vertical scrolling, so it is pity this is not done in one code block.

Taking it all together, the improved version of the plug-in becomes much shorter, and looks like this:

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.scrollSpeed = function(step, speed, easing) {
        var $d = $(document),
            $w = $(window),
            $body = $('html, body')
            root = 0;
        if (window.navigator.msPointerEnabled) { return false }

        $w.on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
            var maxY = $d.height() - $w.height(),
                animation = {};
            animation[maxY > 0 ? 'scrollTop' : 'scrollLeft'] = root = 
                Math.min(maxY > 0 ? maxY : Math.max(0, $d.width() - $w.width()),
                    Math.max(0,
                        ($body.is(':animated') ? root : maxY > 0 ? $d.scrollTop() : $d.scrollLeft()) 
                        + Math.sign(-e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaY || e.originalEvent.detail) * step));
            $body.stop().animate(animation, speed, easing || 'default');
            return false;
        });
    };

    jQuery.easing.default = function (x,t,b,c,d) {
        return -c * ((t=t/d-1)*t*t*t - 1) + b;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: hey sorry for the late reply I took time off over christmas, I first replaced just the root variable like you instructed and it didn't fix the issue of jumping back to the top of the page, so I used the whole new script which you tweaked and there is a bit of an issue now that when you scroll, it actually can't scroll if you're moving the mouse wheel a lot, because it seems to restart whatever easing is on it and so scrolls super slow. Take a look at my site http://danceforovariancancer.com.au to see what the issue is,

Comment: I use `jQuery.scrollSpeed(300, 1300);` to set the step and speed, 300 is step and 1300 is speed, maybe you made changes to strings which use these?

Comment: okay it won't be live on the site when you check but surely you would have noticed while you were developing it or?

Comment: I'll send you a page with your version once sec :) hope you can see the differences http://danceforovariancancer.com.au/stack.html

Comment: Where do you call `jQuery.scrollSpeed`? Note that you really should provide a completely trimmed-down test case, not a full-blown web-site. Also, your main site (not stack), does not have the plug-in functioning at all, as there is a *"jQuery is not defined"* error in the console. So the comparison is not possible.

Comment: to keep my site working normally and show you your script running on mine I made a new js file called jquery.stack.js and it calls itself at the bottom with a $(document).ready(function(){ under the jquery script

Comment: Hmm the main site is running my other plugin, but you're saying it's not loading jquery at all?

Comment: in **js/call.js** included by **stack.html** you have: `jQuery.scrollSpeed(300, 800);`, while in **js/lopuparallax.js** included by the home page you have: `jQuery.scrollSpeed(100, 800);`. It is therefore normal they behave differently.

Comment: nah I just did that for testing, I've reverted it back to 100 and it still behaves like that, what do you think? Your solution fixes the scrolling jumping back up but ads the weird scrolling speed. Could you suggest a best of the two combined?

Comment: There was indeed a problem. I rewrote the plug-in considerably. Let me know if this works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $document = $(document),
    $window = $(window),
    $body = $('html, body'),
    option = easing || 'default',
    root = 0,
    scroll = false,
    scrollY = $document.height() > $window.height(),
    scrollX = $document.width() > $window.width(),
    view;
```

Take a look at scrollY and scrollX vars. The original jQuery.scrollSpeed plugin does not reset now at the top.